# Is there a way to write a local language - independent formula within a format condition in VBA in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, regional-settings

I am writing a excel macro with VBA that contains a simple formula:

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=NOT(AND($L1>360;$K1<45))"
```

However, this does only work, if the language in excel is set to English. If the applicants language is for instance German, it looks like that:

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=NICHT(UND($L1>360;$K1<45))"
```

Is there a way to use a generic one that works for all applicants?

Some requirements regarding the solution:

- It should not be specific (no translation from english into german)
- Also a select case statement with the language ID is not applicable
- There is an option with a function translator: This cannot be applied due to admin restrictions (and I am curious, if there is another way :) )
- Changing the formula to use it within a cell is also not applicable, since I need the format condition there

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Not exactly familiar with this topic and I can't test it out but possible to insert the english formula in a cell's `Formula` property and see if `FormulaLocal` will give you the translated formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually that is not possible, but there is a workaround.

First note that english versions use `,` instead of `;` as separator, so your english formula needs to be `=NOT(AND($L1>360,$K1<45))`.

The workaround is to write that formula to any unused cell.

```
Range("unused_cell").Formula = "=NOT(AND($L1>360,$K1<45))"
```

Then read the localization of that

```
Dim FormulaLocal As String
FormulaLocal = Range("unused_cell").FormulaLocal
```

and use that as condition

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=FormulaLocal
```

That will translate the condition to the correct localisation of your Excel.

Answer (score 2):

The formula for conditional formatting is region specific and there is no option - neither in VBA nor in the GUI - to handle this except you  omit all language specific keywords (or do a "translation" as in the previous answer suggested)

This will work:

```
=($K1<45)*($L1>360)=0
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That worked for this application.