# Conditional Formatting a Range row by row

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to apply some conditionals rules using VBA in a Range.
But I'm very new with conditional formating VBA so I'm a bit lost.

My Users can add rows above of the target range, that mean the range address could be always different.

let's admit that for the exemple, my range is `Worksheets("test").Range("MyBoard")`
("MyBoard" is my range name, currently located at A19:O32)

How can I apply a rule to turn yellow each **rows** of my range **if the first column contains the value "Customer"** ?

```
Sub FormatRange()
   Dim MyRange As Range
   Set MyRange = Worksheets("test").Range("MyBoard")

   MyRange.FormatConditions.Delete
   MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Formula1:="=COUNTIF(MyRange;"*Customer*") > 0"
   MyRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Is "MyBoard" a named ranges? If so, how many column does it have? Then, the formula must count **the specific cell value in the range first column**...

Comment: You may need to change your formula, e.g., `Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A1>1"`, where the `$A1` is important to allow the formatting to occur on that specific row.

Comment: I just edit my post @FaneDuru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next adapted code:

```
Sub FormatRange()
   Dim MyRange As Range, listSep As String
   Set MyRange = Range("MyBoard")

   listSep = Application.International(xlListSeparator)
   MyRange.FormatConditions.Delete
   MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, formula1:="=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & _
                  """Customer""" & listSep & MyRange.cells(1, 1).Address(0, 1) & "))"
   MyRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: @Xodarap Didn't you find some time to test the above code? I updated it. In case of Formatcontitions formula, the separator should be the local list separator (according to localization...).

Comment: @Xodarap Is it so difficult to test the code and send some feedback?

Comment: Hello @FaneDuru I just didn't found the time to test your code last friday. But I just tried it and it's interesting. I have an issue with the formula. I convert it into french and it's working as a "normal rule" in conditional formating option but not by using VBA. The formula keep all "" on it. so nothing happen. I try to find a solution

Comment: In french the formula is : MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, formula1:="=ESTNUM(CHERCHE(" & """Customer""" & listSep & MyRange.cells(1, 1).Address(0, 1) & "))" and when I apply this formula I don't get any error but when I check in Conditional formating the formule is : ="ESTNUM(CHERCHE(""*Customer*"";$A14))"

Comment: @Xodarap Do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed? If possible, I would like to connect to your computer and see, understand and adapt the code to work in your environment...

Comment: That's nice to you, sadly I can't because of the company security policy.

Comment: As a dumb test I just edit the formula like that ''' = "ESTNUM(1)''' and the issue is still here. in the Conditional formating option the formula is '''="ESTNUM(1)"

Comment: @Xodarap Is the formula exactly as you show? I mean `"ESTNUM(CHERCHE(""Customer"";$A14))"`, without "=" as the beginning?

Comment: in my VBA consol it's exactly like that : MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, formula1:="ESTNUM(CHERCHE(" & """ * Customer * """ & listSep & MyRange.Cell(1, 1).Address(0,1) & "))"

Comment: @Xodarap It looks you forgot the initial "=", telling to Excel that it is a formula... But, since `Customer` is not really a variable, please try: `MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, formula1:="=ESTNUM(CHERCHE(""Customer""" & listSep & MyRange.cells(1, 1).Address(0, 1) & "))"`. It should work...

Comment: but in the Conditional formating tab (not vba) the formula become like that : ="ESTNUM(CHERCHE("" * Customer * "";$A14))*

Comment: This shouldn't be possible... Did you try my last suggestion? Where from "*" to appear? Did you copy it from the Conditional Formating edited formula?

Comment: Ho Yes good catch !! I just edit it on my code and now the formula is good but not working ... Customers row stay white ...

Comment: Please, **copy the formula, exactly as it is** here...

Comment: It's all good now, thanks to you.

Comment: What did you do wrongly?

Comment: I added a wrong space between customer and the "*" so the paterne was always wrong

Comment: But such a character (*) should not exist in the formula... It must be `&`... The concatenation character.l

Comment: Anyhow, it should work in the initial way, too. Of course, changing the English formula name with the French one... I tried it in that way, in case you need to adapt it for some other strings (instead of Customer). It looks you took the "*" character form the other answer and mixed things in a wrong way... `SEARCH` is able to search for a **partial** part of a string. No wild card is necessary!

Comment: Ho that's good to know ! Thanks for all the help. I will adapt it for all the other formating I have to do. It should be ok from now

Comment: can I use this technique to apply a background color in the row and also a pattern but only on some columns ?

Comment: Of course, you can, but You must be very careful in setting the range to apply on and formula to be used. Please, place a new question, using my code and ask for what new you want doing. If you tag me here and I am available I will try helping. If not, somebody else will solve the problem having a working pattern, I think...

Comment: ok, I just did it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73276541/using-vba-for-a-conditional-formatting-with-diff%c3%a9rent-rules

Answer (score 1):

Conditional formatting has some very particular format to get an entire row to work.

E.g., If i want to apply a color to each row, between certain columns of a specified range:

```
With .Range(.Cells(1, startColumn), .Cells(lastRow, endColumn))
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A1>1"
    .FormatConditions(1).Font.Italic = True
End With
```

Edit1:  Indicating use of `Find()` for the row containing "Customer" being used for the above code.

```
Sub test()
    With Sheets(1)
        Dim customerCell As Range:  Set customerCell = .Columns(1).Find("Customer")
        If customerCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Dim lastRow As Long:  lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
        With .Range(.Cells(customerCell.Row, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 10))
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=CountIf($A" & customerCell.Row & ",""*Customer*"")"
            .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok that's very different of what I expected, In each formula I found they all start at A1 but my range start (currently) at A19 so how can I adapt that to my situation ? 
I mean it should be dynamic isn't ? today it's A19 but tommorow it could be A40

Comment: @Xodarap You can use `Range.Find().Row` to determine where the first instance of "Customer" occurs, and use that row for the start.  Let me give an update to my answer.

Comment: @Xodarap just posted update; note that I used columns `1` to `10` in the example code.

Comment: Well this solution work ! but only for the row who contains exactly "Customer" in the first column. How can I edit it to apply it also to all row with column "Old Customer" / "New Customer" / "Customer 2021" / "Customer 2022" ??

Comment: @Xodarap `Formula1:="=CountIf($A" & customerCell.Row & ",""*Customer*"")"`.  I updated the post.  You had the `CountIf()` in yours and it would be the way to do it... note the double quotes, `""` is used in this code because you want an actual quotation mark to appear in the string.

Comment: Damn I get an error now ... I will retry that next monday. My company is using a deprecated French version of Excel who is a nightmare so maybe there is an issue with that ... I translated the "CountIf" into "NB.SI" but still not working. Thanks for your help already. I come back Monday

Comment: @Xodarap what error and on what line?  the `CountIf()` is what shows up when you type into a cell in excel `=NB.SI(B3:B10,"*Snack*")`, so that should be your equivalent.

Comment: I got this error : incorrect argument or procedure call into the line .FormatConditions.Add

Comment: in french the line is probably something like that : .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=NB.SI($A" & customerCell.Row & ",""*Customer*"")" because CountIf is not reconize but it's still not working

Comment: @Xodarap I'm sorry I won't be able to help further with the French part of the set-up; regarding what was asked, this should get you 99% of the way there, though the specific syntax on the version may be problematic.  Even your example uses `CountIf()`, so I'm curious:  What happened between your posted code and the specific computer in question?

Comment: Hello @Cyril I gave this exemple before to understand that, I have to translate into french formula. I will try to use what you gave me and find what's wrong with it today. Thanks already for all the help

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what your are looking for:

```vb
Sub FormatRange()
   Dim MyRange As Range
   Set MyRange = Worksheets("test").Range("MyBoard")

    Dim startAddress As String
    startAddress = MyRange.Cells(1, 1).Address(False, True) ' will return e.g. $A19 in your case
    
    Dim formula As String
    'formula = startAddress & " = ""customer"""      'exact customer
    formula = "ISNUMBER(FIND(""customer""," & startAddress & "))" ' *customer*
    
    Dim fc As FormatCondition
    With MyRange
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        Set fc = .FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & formula)
        fc.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    End With
    
End Sub
```

You have to reference the first cell within your range - and "fix" the column --> `.Address(False, True)`  will return $A19 in your case.

Then you need to build a valid string for the formula to pass to the format condition

You need double quotes for "customer" when building the string.

Comment: Sadly I got an error at the row :
Set fc = .FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & formula)

the error is : incorrect call or argument

Comment: Made a change to the formula - it is a bit tricky for me to test as I have a German excel - and there you have to put the german version of the formula for format condition

Comment: Same story for me with a deprecated french version ...

Comment: Will there be users of the sheet with other languages? In French you would need `"ESTNUM(TROUVE("customer""," & startAddress & "))"`  --> https://en.excel-translator.de/translator/ helps translating the formulas.

Comment: Regarding an international version, look here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/69220627/16578424

Comment: Just spotted an error - one double quote is missing: `"ESTNUM(TROUVE(""customer""," & startAddress & "))"`