# Using VBA for a conditional formatting with différent rules

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

How can I set a rules to turn the row backround Yellow and also apply a pattern to some specific columns of this same row, only using VBA ?

```
Sub FormatRange()
Dim MyRange As Range, listSep As String
Set MyRange = Range("MyBoard")

listSep = Application.International(xlListSeparator)
MyRange.FormatConditions.Delete
MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, formula1:="=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & _
              """Customer""" & listSep & MyRange.cells(1, 1).Address(0, 1) & "))"
MyRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
MyRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Pattern = xlGray75
End Sub
```

Can I just specify the column letter at the same time as the Range ? (column B/C/E/H)

Comment: I am afraid I cannot understand what you mean by "Can I just specify the column letter at the same time as the Range ? (column B/C/E/H)"... Do you mean to apply the `FormatConditions` for only a column, or for discontinuous columns range? Something like "B2:C10", "E2:E10", "H2:H10"

Comment: My row has already a yellow background but now I want to apply a specific pattern to the colomn A, C, E and H of this row. dépending of the target (here it's customer) the pattern will be apply to different column.

Comment: Do you mean that `"MyBoard"` named range contains the mentioned columns and separated of the `FormatConditions` already applied with the above code, do you want a second one to be applied only to the mentioned columns (**inside the named range**)?

Comment: Ho yes of course, All columns and row are part of "MyBoard" range. A second one could be good but with the same rules as the first one (yellow background)

Comment: If so, please show us the address of this range. Then, do you want applying the pattern based on **the same formula2 condition**?

Comment: the address can be différent each time. currently "MyBoard" is located at (A15:O28)

Comment: I am talking in terms of columns (only). Should the columns be also variable? Then, I asked before: "do you want applying the pattern based on **the same formula2 condition**?"

Comment: the format of a row depend of the value of the first column of this row. if the first column contain "Customer" the row backround have to be yellow and the columns A,C,E,H have a pattern. But yes if the first column contain something else the color background will be different and the pattern will be apply to different columns too. I hope it's clear .

Comment: I also hope I understood what you mean... I will prepare an answer.

Comment: Please, test the code I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next adapted code. It assumes that you need, **for the same `Formula2` condition (formula), to place a specific pattern only on the mention columns (of the named range):

```
Private Sub FormatRange()
   Dim MyRange As Range, listSep As String
   Set MyRange = Range("MyBoard")

   listSep = Application.International(xlListSeparator)
   MyRange.FormatConditions.Delete
   MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, formula1:="=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & _
                    """Customer""" & listSep & MyRange.cells(1, 1).Address(0, 1) & "))"                                                                
   MyRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
   
   'the code new part:
   Dim myRng As Range
   
   Set myRng = Intersect(MyRange, MyRange.Parent.Range("B:C, E:E, H:H"))
   myRng.FormatConditions.Delete
   myRng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, formula1:="=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & _
                     """Customer""" & listSep & MyRange.cells(1, 1).Address(0, 1) & "))"
   myRng.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Pattern = xlGray75
End Sub
```

Comment: It's perfect, thanks a lot ! I just added a yellow background at the same time as the pattern and now I got exactly what I want

Comment: @Xodarap   Yes, the previously added `Interior` (background) has been deleted by `myRng.FormatConditions.Delete`... I was not sure that the Yellow interior color must also exist in that discontinuous range. I did not test the code, I only thought it will work. Anyhow, I did not understand if the Yellow part must exist in the second created range and I thought that you can take care of it, if necessary... :)